# How to disable a responsive mobile menu jquery command for desktop view

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I've built a jquery responsive nav menu. It hides the expanded list items when clicked in mobile view as wanted. But also hides them when in desktop view (not wanted). I'm a complete newbie to jquery. I've tried enquire.js but it doesn't seem to work. I know it should, just not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I've looked through all similar problems on this forum but can't seem to find an answer that works for me. I'm sure it's a very simple few lines I haven't been able to locate after thorough searching.Here's the (v.newbie)code I'm struggling with:

```
    $(function() {          
        var pull        = $('#pull');
            menu        = $('nav ul');
            menuHeight  = menu.height();

        $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            menu.slideToggle();
        });

        $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 510 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
                menu.removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
        $(".scroll").click(function(){
                $("nav ul").hide(1000);
            });
    });
```

I've uploaded what I'm working on to JSFiddle here:
 http://jsfiddle.net/ConorMac/9qdd8784/

As you'll see it behaves the way I want it to behave when the break-point goes below 510px. But I just can't for the life of me get the list items to stay put when above 510px! Any help would be greatly appreciated. And a (very basic I'm sure!) lesson learned.

Cheers.

Comment: can you elaborate more on "also hides them when in desktop view"? I don't understand what is expected here because it seems to me, it is working just fine. what I am not understanding?

Comment: Sorry, should have elaborated more here. If you increase/drag the viewport screen width past 510px and then click on a menu item the list disappears.

Comment: is it not because you are calling `.hide()` on the `nav ul` element?

Comment: i suppose you need a condition in the `scroll` click function as well, to **not** hide the `nav ul` element if the `width` is greater than `510px`. makes sense?

Comment: Yep, makes perfect sense Tahir, but as I said I'm a bit of a newbie to jquery and I've been struggling on exactly how to write that bit of code. I tried wrapping the .scroll function with  

 if ($('nav ul').width() < 510) {

Any ideas? I'm sure it's simple.

Comment: Copy the `if` clause from `.resize()` above, wrap around the `$('nav ul').hide(1000);` line so that the whole thing can become: `$('.scroll').click(function() { if ($(window).width() < 510) { $('nav ul').hide(1000); }});`. this should do.

Comment: apologies for the lack of formatting in my reply. Not sure how to!

Comment: YES!! Brilliant. Thanks so much Tahir.

Comment: No problems. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use plain CSS - the `@media` tag...

```
@media (max-width: 510px){
    ul{
        < styles go here >
    }
}
```

Whatever styles you apply to the `ul` will only apply when the screen size is 510px or below.

Comment: Yep. I have the @media  in the css already. Its the jquery command that's messin' me up. Thanks though.